# final specifier vs fdevirtualize

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, optimization

Both `-fdevirtualize` and `-fdevirtualize-speculatively` flags are enabled at optimization levels `-O2`, `-O3` and `-Os`.

> `-fdevirtualize`
>
> Attempt to convert calls to virtual functions to direct calls. This is done both within a procedure and interprocedurally as part of
>   indirect inlining (-findirect-inlining) and interprocedural constant
>   propagation (-fipa-cp). Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.
>
> `-fdevirtualize-speculatively`
>
> Attempt to convert calls to virtual functions to speculative direct calls. Based on the analysis of the type inheritance graph,
>   determine for a given call the set of likely targets. If the set is
>   small, preferably of size 1, change the call into a conditional
>   deciding between direct and indirect calls. The speculative calls
>   enable more optimizations, such as inlining. When they seem useless
>   after further optimization, they are converted back into original
>   form.

I was wondering if using the `final` specifier made the program more efficient when we were already using these flags?

Comment: Yes, using `final` improves the abilities of the optimizer regarding your code. That can easily be verified using the assembler output, though http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c3d5c09c9cb31dd . In the non-final path, the compiler only speculatively devirtualizes apparently.